# How to change timing of my mocap BVH and how to optimize keyframes

Tags: animation, keyframes

I have a BVH file from my Mocap suit that contains 2892 frames, where each frame is a keyframe. The animation runs very slow at about 1/3 speed.

My questions are:

1. How can I speed up my animation by removing about 2/3 of keyframes? I have found out that I can open NLA editor and change timing from 0 - 2892 frames to 0 - 900 frames and it will do what I need, yet it disallows all future keyframe edits.
2. How can I optimize my keyframes? Many of these keyframes are not necessary and can be dealt with interpolation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **[Simplify Curves](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Curve/Curve_Simplify)** addon, which is already with your Blender.

- Enable the Addon;
- Switch to **Graph Editor**, select all curves that you want to simplify, press <kbd>Space</kbd> and search for *Simplify Curves*. Then press <kbd>F6</kbd> to tweak the *Error* theshold.

[image]

[image]

To be more accurate, you have to remove those unneeded "interpolated" keys manually, which needs time.