# How do I smooth out an f-curve?

Tags: animation, modifiers, fcurves

So maybe it´s a dumb question to the more experienced users, but I´m a noob at animating, so I tried to make a Basic intro(basically a world where there is a simple camera movement to the text which is wobbling to the Music). But the Text is just wobbling way too fast so I have to smooth out the wobbling of the text, how do I do this?

Comment: Check this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61428/how-can-i-simplify-or-resample-a-bezier-curve and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18729/how-to-change-timing-of-my-mocap-bvh-and-how-to-optimize-keyframes/18730

Comment: Is your fcurve a baked sound? If so you need to unbake the curve first.