# How to smooth out baked sound to f curves?

Tags: animation, scale, audio, fcurves

Ok, I have several scaling animations synced to audio via "Bake sound to f curves" and I've applied an envelope modifier to control the max value the curve can hit. The curve looks like this -

[image]

This results in a pretty jumpy animation due to the jagged nature of the line or maybe the easing of the curve itself. Tried changing interpolation mode but this did nothing.

How can I smooth out the animation produced by "bake sound to f curves" ? Is this addon relevant [How to change timing of my mocap BVH and how to optimize keyframes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18729/how-to-change-timing-of-my-mocap-bvh-and-how-to-optimize-keyframes/18730) ? Or is it in the easing settings?

Comment: it's always tricky to do anything with baked curves. check this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19357/smoothing-a-baked-f-curve

Comment: @wilks perfect, this works. My only issue is I dont know how to apply my f curve modifiers before I unbake the curve

Comment: then i think you need to apply the f-curve modifiers with Bake Curve (`Alt`+`C`) then delete the modifiers, then unbake. but might be better to add your modifiers as the last step instead, that would give you more flexibility later

Answer (score 2):

I have two solutions, one requiring an external program.

1. Smooth the source WAV in Audacity before baking. How to smooth it
   will depend on what sounds you're trying to extract. I recommend
   narrowing it to a freq range with a combination of high pass and low
   pass (or Graphic EQ, put all ranges to 0 except the ones you want,
   and maybe give those a bit of a 'curve' with neighbouring
   frequencies so you get ramping.
2. Or you can just un-bake curve in Blender and then press <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>  <kbd>O</kbd> to smooth.